# How to ignore file in Heroku but not in Git

Tags: git, heroku, gitignore

I'm using Heroku and my problem is "simple", I have an index.html file that displays the folder structure when on development. It basically helps me traverse different demos when running a local server.

Question: How can I ignore that file when deploying to Heroku but keep it in git for other developers to benefit from it.

If I add it to .gitignore it should ignore it in Heroku, but it will also ignore it in the version control system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably do that using a [.slugignore file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-).

Sorry I can't be more specific - haven't used .slugignore files before.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rename that file to `index.html_template` add that to your GIT Repository and ignore the original `index.html` file.

Then every developer has to copy them if they need them.

Comment: Thanks but telling each dev to copy and paste it when needed is not my idea of a solution. I might not even have any type of communication with a developer working with it.

Comment: On the other hand, when initiating the local server, I could just run a grunt task like grunt-copy and copy and paste it, keeping it in the .gitignore. Too much trouble tho.